# SKShapeNode(path: path) does not draw

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, skshapenode

Here i am attempting to draw gridLines for a grid whose border I have successfully created as a SKShapeNode however I am unable to get the lines to be visible when running this code.

```
func drawGridLines() {
        print("drawing")
        for row  in 0...40 {
            let path = CGPathCreateMutable()
            CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, grid.frame.origin
                .x , grid.frame.origin.y + CGFloat(row * 10))
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, grid.frame.width, grid.frame.origin.y + CGFloat(row * 10))
            let shape = SKShapeNode(path: path)
            shape.path = path
            shape.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame))
            shape.fillColor = UIColor.redColor()
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            shape.lineWidth = 10
            addChild(shape)

            for col in 0...90 {
                print("y")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code to my project and run, I clearly see those blue grids lines. However, I don't have the variable `grid` so I change that to `self` which is `SKScene`. So I think you have some problem with this `grid`, maybe it's out of the screen. Put more codes about the it or change that by yourself, have some tests.

[image]

Comment: Agh! there was something about the grid variable. Thanks bruv

Comment: @HyakubEdwardHerring Good to hear, could you accept the answer?

Comment: This code only works when self.frame is called. This is unfortunate coo you how to avoid this. @ Valar Morghulis                                                shape.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame))